Variable Selection and model prediction
In a supervised problem, I used randomForest for variable selection to identify the most important features.
Question: am I required to use a random forest model for subsequent predictions, or can I perform feature selection using one model and then make predictions using a different model?

You can do whatever you want, if this will work is a different question. For ex. using a RF and then following it with a linear model as-is could produce quite bad predictions.

This could be true if we select the variables using a linear model and apply a linear model for the prediction, since the approach is linear in both cases. However, if I want to use a deep learning model for the prediction, do you think it will work well and why?

Every model is different. Using random forest to get the feature importances you will get what is important for Random Forest but this does not mean that its the same for Logistic Regression. You can do a simple test. Get RF importances and then get the absolute coeffs of a logistic regression. Are they the same?

The results are not the same" for both Lasso and Random Forest, which makes me wonder which selection would work well with my deep learning model. Additionally, I have a question: do you think that autoencoders provide better feature selection than linear models?
